# std::thread overload not resolved (with right arguments)

Tags: c++, overloading, std, stdthread

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A(){}
    void m(std::string* s)
    {
     cout<<*s;
    }
    void m(std::string s)
   {
     cout<<s;
   }
};    

int main()
{
 A a;
 string str="hi!\n";
 std::thread(&A::m,a,&str);

}
```

this doesn't compile; it gives:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, A&, std::string*)’
```

if I remove the second member it compiles! why? I can't use overloaded methods in std::thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but you have to pick the desired overload manually:

```
std::thread th(static_cast<void (A::*)(std::string*)>(&A::m),a,&str);
```

Or you could use a lambda:

```
std::thread th([&] { a.m(&str); });
```

Addendum: The reason this can't be deduced automatically is, in short, that the compiler looks only skin-deep when searching for the right constructor. Finding (making!) the right constructor from the relevant constructor template of the `std::thread` class involves [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), and template argument deduction looks, as a rule, only at the signatures and not the internals of a function template (in this case a constructor template, which is for our purposes the same). The relevant constructor template is

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

...which does not in itself say anything about the interplay of `f` and `args` in the depths of the implementation. There is not enough information in it to decide that only one overrload of `A::m` can work, so the ambiguity cannot be resolved, and you have to do it manually.

Whether it is actually possible and/or practical to make the compiler look deeper to resolve such ambiguities is an interesting question. I imagine it would be quite a challenge. Either way, it has not yet been done.

Comment: @volperossa The error has nothing to do with `std::thread`. `&A::m` itself is ambiguous because the compiler doesn't know which `m` you're referring to.

Comment: I extended the answer a bit to address that. Superficially, because explaining template argument deduction in detail is tedious; the rules are fairly complex. There's a link, if you're interested.

Comment: @volperossa: If `std::thread`'s constructor were a part of the core language then, yes. But it's not. It's just a function from a library (albeit the standard library). It has to conform to the rules of the language and without any special treatment `&A::m` is ambiguous here. The _language_ doesn't know that it could theoretically figure out which overload to use from the other arguments, because it has no idea what those arguments mean.

Comment: What the constructor does is roughly equivalent to: `auto f = &A::m; auto obj = a; auto arg = &str; (obj.*f)(arg);` and it can't determine the type of `f` in the first statement. The function call that happens later is too late to influence the type deduction that is needed for `auto f = &A::m;`

Comment: thanks! just a thing:
std::thread th(static_cast<void (A::*)(std::string*)>(&A::m),a,&str);
the second parameter would be a pointer to the object owner of the method...so..it wouldn't be &a?

Comment: I did not know threads could run lamdbas like this, thank you